# How to generate array of arrays with dynamic size with numpy?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'd like to get array of numpy arrays with ranged lengths like this:

```
>>> source = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> get_array_of_arrays_with_min_length(source, 5)
    array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
           [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
           [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
           [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
           [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
           [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
```

How to do this with less code?

Comment: That looks like array of lists. Can you confirm?

Comment: A good question might be: what is an array of arrays with dynamic size for you? Depending on what you want `NumPy` might not be the right tool for you.

Comment: There's been many similar questions. Look up ragged arrays

Comment: Less code than what? You didn't provide anything to compare with.

Answer (score 1):

Generate your lists,

```
l = [ [i+1 for i in range(x+1, 10)] for x in range(6)]
```

Then create your array.

```
a = numpy.array(l)
```

If I had to guess what your function should do,

```
def get_array_of_arrays(source, m):
    return [ [ i for i in source if i>x] for x in range(m+1)]
```

That would give you the result you've requested from the inputs provided. Really the take-home idea here is to make a list of lists.

Comment: `range(x+1:10)` is not valid Python, should be `range(x+1, 10)`

Comment: I think a cleaner version of this double range is: `[list(range(n, 11)) for n in range(1, 7)]`